# SQL Join 3 tables to output names

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 3 tables

Customer

(CustID, FirstName, LastName)

Artist

(ArtistID, FirstName, LastName)

Customer_Artist_Interest

(CustID, ArtistID)

I have to link the 3 tables in which the names of all the customers and the names of the artists each customer has an interest in, in alphabetical order of artist last name within customer last name. The output should look like:

```
A.LastName    A.FirstName     C.LastName    C.FirstName
```

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Try join and order by customer name ,artist name

Answer (score 0):

A couple of joins should do the trick:

```
SELECT   a.LastName, a.FirstName, c.LastName, c.FirstName
FROM     Customer c
JOIN     Customer_Artist_Interest cai ON c.CustId = cai.CustId 
JOIN     Artist a ON cai.ArtistId = a.ArtistId
ORDER BY a.LastName, a.FirstName, c.LastName, c.FirstName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.LastName,
       c.FirstName,
       a.LastName,
       a.FirstName,
  from Customer c,
       Artist a,
       Customer_Artist_Interest i
 where c.CustID = i.CustID
   and a.ArtistID = i.ArtistID
 order by c.LastName, c.FirstName, a.LastName, a.FirstName;
```